# Evolutive neural network on Super Mario World

Tags: artificial-intelligence, evolutionary-algorithm

I'm trying to run this application of the NEAT algorithm so it can play SMW, but instead it just stays on the select level section, where it can not learn anything. It work with the EmuHawk and a LUA console that the emulator provides. Here's the link for the source code:   `https://pastebin.com/ZZmSNaHX`

Link for EmuHawk:  `https://github.com/TASEmulators/BizHawk-Prereqs/releases`

And link for the SMW: [Link removed]

[enter image description here]    (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y96YK.png)
Here u can see how it is on the like 300 spieces genome 3 but it just won't learn anything on that section. I need him to play.

I tried to change the config for the DP1.STATE but it won't work, 'cause that  was the first thing causing issues on the program "NLua.Exceptions.LuaScriptException: [string "main"]:35: attempt to get length of global 'ButtonNames' (a nil value)" bu it's already fixed.

Comment: Do not add links to pirated games!

Answer (score 0):

[SethBling's MarI/O](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qv6UVOQ0F44) is 7 years old. If you use a version of BizHawk from that time, the script may run without errors.